# Eclipse Indigo update/android-plugins update are not working

Tags: eclipse

I want to setup my eclipse indigo IDE for android development. I use windows 7 32 bit. But when I want to update my eclipse or try to android plugins I have the following problem.

**'Contracting software sites' has encountered a problem**

**An internal error occurred during: "Contacting Software Sites".
org/sat4j/minisat/core/AssertingClauseGenerator'**

While installing android plugins I get

**org/sat4j/minisat/core/AssertingClauseGenerator**

**java.lang.noClassDefFounderror**

How can I get rid of this?